# Why does Webmaster Impression Numbers and Local Search Volume does not match?

Tags: google-local-search, impressions

I a website which is ranking on top 5 positions for some keywords; however, when I check the impressions from Google webmaster for the same keywords it is very very very less. Hence, I wanted to understand even if I am ranking on 1 position by impression share should be the same as the local search volume. Please help me its urgent.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the so called "filter bubble". Even though for query "x" there might be 1000 searches, it is possible that it only ranks as number 1 for a specific group of people, that are known to be interested in subject x (as deemed by search history).

So for lets say 50% of those searches your website could come up as number 1, but for the other 50% it could be in 2nd page or even further.

In other words: if your web-site ranks as no1 when YOU  search for it using that query, it doesnt neccesarilly means that it comes up as no1 for anyone else.

EDIT:

In addition to that, it may take some time for informaion in webmaster tools to get up to date, it is not real time.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Google's Webmaster Tools should not be trusted at all - Many companies do not even look at webmaster tools for such reports and use paid subscriptions to actually monitor things a hell of a lot better than webmaster tools does.

Don't trust anything you read on their, just use it as a estimate and if you see something which is unlikely then its simply wrong.